# How can I get multiple Jenkins jobs with lib dependency work ( SVN repo)

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have SVN repo that includes  many code  dependencies between the different projects .
Each project is set as Jenkins job .

For example,  to compile project A  I need project A lib and a bunch of other shared libs ( hundreds of MBs) .

One of the architectures for setting up Jenkins job is to set multiple  "Repository URL" -per each lib from the trunk and then when any of those is triggered, Jenkins (the plugin actually ) will  checkout only needed code for this job. However  I end up with having to pull gigabytes of data multiple times  since each job will pull all those  shared libs by it's own...  Also since it's "pull " model and there are many URL's  and many jobs I'm afraid it won't work well in long run.

Another thought was to clone the trunk and then to parse the changes and that way to trigger the relevant job . However  this is not KISS solution and it's not a solid one .

Are there another better suited solutions for such problem?

Comment: you can run a script in jenkins to do anything you want

Answer (score 0):

Trigger a script using `jenkins`. `Pst-commit` hook should bear the logic.

Also Check if you can use [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) Parameterized trigger plugin.